# Rails default_scope being applied to update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using default_scope in rails to siphon out anything that has a value of is_deleted = true (anything with this value should never be shown, but I still want to keep the row in the database). But there is one controller action that should actually undelete something (sets is_deleted = false), but it's failing because the default_scope is being applied. It's my understanding that the default_scope is only applied when selecting / creating a record but not when updating (source: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Default/ClassMethods.html).

> The default_scope is also applied while creating/building a record. It is not applied while updating a record.

I know that I can use the .unscoped method, but it just seems that this is counter-intuitive. Am I misunderstanding the docs?

**app/models/post.rb**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope where(:is_deleted => false)
```

**app/controllers/posts_controller.rb**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
def undelete
  @post = Post.update(params[:id], :is_deleted => false)
  render :action => :success if @post.save
end
```

**error**

> Couldn't find Post with id=1 [WHERE "posts"."is_deleted" = 'f']

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line from documentation you mentioned (`The default_scope is also applied while creating/building a record. It is not applied while updating a record.`) - says that default_scope attributes are applied to all models on building/creation:

in your case all new records will have `is_deleted` attribute set to false

but on updating, if you get a record from the db, change one attribute (for example `title`), and call `save` - the `is_deleted` attribute will not be forced to `false`, as it happened on creation.

But the `update` method you use ([you can check it here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update/class)) just uses `find` inside, which always uses the `default_scope`

The solution would just be to use `unscoped` method

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
def undelete
  @post = Post.unscoped.update(params[:id], :is_deleted => false)
  render :action => :success if @post.save
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation, that makes perfect sense :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are getting hung up on semantics.  Rails has to find your record before you can update it.  For Rails to find the record you need to use the .unscoped method.  To see how Rails applies the scope value you can:

```
raise Post.find(:id => id, :is_deleted => true).to_sql
```

You should see something like:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE `id`=123 AND `is_deleted` = true AND `is_deleted` = false
```

The .unscoped method tells Rails not to apply the last condition. Rails doesn't skip the default scope, even if you provide an additional condition for the same field.

Comment: Ah, I see. So the Post.update() is actually calling Post.find() first? That makes perfect sense - but the documentation is very confusing saying that it doesn't use default_scope when updating. That would mean that it will never work since update() calls find() first, right?